# Video resolution when capturing a full-screen recording via ffmpeg on Mac OS X

Tags: video, ffmpeg, resolution, macos-highsierra, screen-recorder

I have a 15-inch 2017 *MacBook Pro* running *Mac OS X* 10.13 (High Sierra):
[image]
The default display supports screen resolutions up to `2880x1800`, despite the maximum resolution selectable via the standard UI is limited to `1920x1200` (see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180239)):
[image]

Now, I'm trying to capture a full-screen recording via `ffmpeg`, using the [`avfoundation`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop#macOS) device, in full resolution (i. e. w/o any sub-sampling):

```
ffmpeg -y -v error -hide_banner -f avfoundation -i 1:none -threads 0 -f mp4 -vcodec mpeg4 -r 25/1 -qscale:v 1 output.mp4
```

Strangely, when the screen resolution varies between `1024x640` and `1920x1200` (i. e. is selectable via the "scaled list" in the *Mac OS X* preferences), the size of the resulting video raster is always a quadruple of the screen resolution:

- `1024x640` → `2048x1280`
- ...
- `1920x1200` → `3840x2400`

[image]

If, on the other hand, I set the screen resolution to the maximum of `2880x1800` using the [`screenresolution`](https://github.com/jhford/screenresolution) utility, the size of `ffmpeg` output will be identical to the screen resolution.

In both cases, the `-video_size` option will be ignored by `ffmpeg`.

The above is only true for the built-in display: for any external displays, screen resolution and captured video resolution are always the same, regardless of the scale level.

#### Questions:

1. Why does `ffmpeg` (or, rather, the `avfoundation` input device) exhibit such inconsistencies?
2. How do I force `ffmpeg` to always use the current display resolution when capturing the screen? I would rather not enable sub-sampling (`-vf scale=...`) to affect the resulting raster size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a known `ffmpeg` issue: [Should retain pixel density metadata from HiDPI/Retina screen recordings](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7045).